# Невозможно включить ноутбук hp дальше логотипа заставки

Tags: стек

Отображается "Обнаружено переполнение стекового буфера в данном приложении. Это переполнение может позволить злоумышленнику получить управление над данным приложением". Нажимая "ок" или крестик ничего не изменяется, то есть ноутбук не может включиться и отображается лишь значок загрузки на темном фоне.
Перед такой ситуацией было "Приближается время перезапуска ...". Много раз пробовали включать и выключать ноутбук, но ситуация не изменялась